# avoid loosing custom change in vendored dependency when updating dependencies

Tags: git, go, dependency-management, vendor

I have a golang project using dep with a `vendor` directory.

for some reason, I had to modify the code of one of the vendored dependency. **This change can't be pushed to the upstream repository**.

How can I keep updating my vendored dependency, without loosing my change ?

Comment: You can't. Those two ideals are in necessary conflict. The best you can do is re-apply your changes, manually resolving any conflicts, after updating the dependency.

Comment: @Flimzy thanks for the answer, I guess I already knew it...

Comment: It's worth mentioning, there may be tools that make this task easier for you. The simplest might be to just fork your dependency, and then handle any merge conflicts in that repository, rather than in your `/vendor/` folder. Whether that's feasible/easy depends on the complexity of the package. There are also other patch-management tools (quilt comes to mind). AFAIK, none interface cleanly with the Go ecosystem, but it may be possible to shoe-horn something in.

Comment: @Flimzy sadly I can't fork the dependency, because I have another vendored dependency that import it... For the moment I'll keep re-applying my change with `git cherry-pick` and see how it goes

Comment: That's the approach I've usually taken, too. Good luck.

Comment: If your dependency is a git repository you can look into [git sub-trees](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging) too. That is fairly complicated, requires special workflows for updating, and easy to mess up; but if done correctly it works well if you have many patches. If you want to try it, do that on a copy of your repository. As long as cherry-picking works for you, stick with that. We have all vendor patches committed as .patch files, so it's easy to re-apply them after an update. Also write tests that make sure all patches are applied correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Make a fork and when your dependency gets updated, rebase.